# IDA Flair all functions skipped when creating .pat file

Tags: ida, tools

I'm trying to create .pat file with IDA Flair tools, but it skips all the functions.
Here is what I did:

```
pelf.exe tier0.lib tier0.pat
tier0.lib: skipped 395, total 395
```

I also tried other tools like pcf and plb and it didn't work.

here is my input file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/xk2gxp9ja8hm00v/tier0.lib

Help?

Comment: It'd be much easier to help if you could upload your input files somewhere for us to check them.

Comment: ok, I added the link

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a tool the detect the library file format(coff, omf, elf)

Comment: This file is very strange, it looks like an `ar` archive,  but `ar tv` on it lists just a few hundred tier0.dll entries, and extracting them (making sure every file gets renamed to something different) yields lots of files that don't seem to be in any standard format. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I downloaded it from Valve Source sdk, here: https://goo.gl/3wPsw9

Comment: It's dynamic library lib. IDA flair plugin is use static library.